# I can't understand linux hook function return 1337?

Tags: c, hook

Now I loot at a article! I get the hook code. The code is here:

```c
int system(const char *command){
    printf("HOOK: system(\"%s\")",command);
    return 1337;
}

int fork(void){
    return 1337;
}

Now I hava a question! Why the return is 1337?

Thanks to answer my question!
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but when you `return 1337` then it doesn't seem surprising when the return is `1337`. Can you elaborate on what this code does a bit further and explain what you are expecting?

Comment: i suspect its like 'return 42;' just a joke 'leet'

Comment: oh! I think the 1337 is only a return code! I return 1, also get a right result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depend on your sub-system, return code 1337 is what handled by others like cloud or somewhere in your internal code.
basically this we define for error handling or to determine the failure cases.
like calling thread might be called this as

`if (1337 != system(command)) {
          /* error statement */
          printf("...");
}`

So in short this is not specific to 1337 you can use any return value.